# Why "expected named lifetime parameter" in a generic function

Tags: generics, rust

If I write a function like this:

```
fn parse_json<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>>(s: &'a str) -> Vec<T> {
    serde_json::from_str(s).unwrap()
}
```

it works as expected.
But if I try to do the same w/o explicitly declaring lifetimes, like this:

```
fn parse_json<T: Deserialize>(s: &str) -> Vec<T> {
    serde_json::from_str(s).unwrap()
}
```

I get a compiler error:

```
| fn parse_json<T: Deserialize>(s: &str) -> Vec<T> {
|                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected named lifetime parameter
```

Why? Is there a reason for the compiler to require **explicit** lifetime declaration in this case?

If I hadn't used a generic but a concrete type, I wouldn't need to *explicitly* declare any lifetimes:

```
fn parse_json(s: &str) -> Vec<MyStruct>   // that compiles file
```

That, I believe, is due to the so called **lifetime elision rules**. Question is, why doesn't the version with a generic return type get covered by the elision rules as well?

Comment: cause compile doesn't guess it yet

Comment: Because the lifetime elision rules only apply to _references_, not to generic parameters, so you must write `Deserialze<'a>`. At which point you also have to say that the lifetime of the references is the same as the generic parameter, so you need to state them explicitly too.

Comment: @Jmb It also seems to apply to other kinds of lifetime, so e.g. [this compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a3c38fef491864606c7aee6c31de58f0) even though `MyStruct` is not a reference.

Answer (score 2):

Lifetime elision applies to function arguments and return types, but it does not currently apply to trait bounds, such as `T: Deserialize`.

> Why? Is there a reason for the compiler to require explicit lifetime declaration in this case?

I don't know for sure, but in general, the lifetime elision rules are fairly restricted, presumably to make them easier to understand and reduce the chances of introducing confusing compiler "magic".

---

Note that lifetime elision ***is*** supported in generic parameters, but it is semi-deprecated (see the [`elided_lifetimes_in_paths`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/allowed-by-default.html#elided-lifetimes-in-paths) lint):

```rust
struct Foo<'a>(&'a str);

// Compiles, but causes a warning with `#![warn(rust_2018_idioms)]`
fn bar1(s: &str) -> Foo { Foo(s) }

// Compiles, does not cause warning
fn bar2(s: &str) -> Foo<'_> { Foo(s) }
```